# Paypal Adaptive Payments Pay API operation returns Invalid Request Parameter "receiver" even though provided

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am attempting an implicit Pay API operation. I keep receiving a "Invalid request parameter: receiver cannot be null" error though I am sending along the receiver as specified in the paypal api docs. I include the API credentials as request headers.

Here is the request payload

```
request['payload']={
'actionType' : 'PAY', 
'senderEmail': 'sender@company.com',
'receiverList' : {'receiver': [{ 'amount': '10.0', 'email':'recepient@company.com' }]}, 
'currencyCode' : 'SGD',
'requestEnvelope' : {
    "errorLanguage":"en_US",    # Language used to display errors
    "detailLevel":"ReturnAll"   # Error detail level
    },
'ipnNotificationUrl': 'http://xxxxxxxx',
'cancelUrl': 'http://xxxxxxxxx',
'returnUrl': 'http://xxxxxxxxxx'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was on my side - though paypal's error message didn't help much. I did 
not encode the python dict object to json before sending the request to paypal.

```
import json
payload = json.dumps(request['payload'])
```

Hope this helps someone.